# when using inertia-link JavaScript charts/button/links not working it is working once page refreshed

Tags: inertiajs

Hi I am using Laravel 8 with Inertiajs  vue3 with Metronic 8 admin theme.
when I am using inertia-link  JavaScript charts/button/links not working  it is working one page refreshed
JS charts woks and button also work  plz help where I am wrong

My Package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"name": "vue-3",
"description": "Laravel Inertia Bs5 and Vue3 App",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.8.4",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.3.5",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.4",
    "@kirschbaum-development/laravel-translations-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.0.11",
    "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.10.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
    "v-offline": "^1.3.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.6",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
    "vue3-geolocation": "^1.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "googlemaps-vue3": "^2.0.4",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7",
    "vue3-google-map": "^0.7.9"
}
```

my app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');
// Import modules...
import { createApp, h, Vue } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';    
const el = document.getElementById('app');
const app = createApp({});



createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            return require(`./Pages/${name}`).default
                      }),
})
.mixin({ methods: { route } })
.use(InertiaPlugin)
.mount(el);
```

Here is the link of repository https://github.com/ClickerVinod/laravelinertiajs

see this video clip
https://youtu.be/XG3ZUPTfcjU

Comment: Can you add the following info to your question: 1) the relevant part of your Vuejs component (the code which renders the Inertia link) and 2) any error messages you see in the dev console of your browser.

Comment: hi  thanks for suggestion  here is the link of project https://github.com/ClickerVinod/laravelinertiajs

Comment: hi @Vinod. I see you put it in a lot of effort in trying to communicate the problem you have. Thank you. However the purpose of my suggestion is that the relevant and detailed error messages are included with the question - as code, not as links or videos. This way it becomes reproducible for someone who's trying to help you. Please see this SO page for more info on how to (re)formulate your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I faced same issue with laravel,inertia,vue3, Did you solve the problem?